# bash loop skip commented lines

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looping over lines in a file.  I just need to skip lines that start with "#".
How do I do that?

```
 #!/bin/sh 

 while read line; do
    if ["$line doesn't start with #"];then
     echo "line";
    fi
 done < /tmp/myfile
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
while read line; do
  case "$line" in \#*) continue ;; esac
  ...
done < /tmp/my/input
```

Frankly, however, it is often clearer to turn to `grep`:

```
grep -v '^#' < /tmp/myfile | { while read line; ...; done; }
```

Comment: You could also do something too clever with `expr` or suffix removal (e.g., `[ -z "${line%%#*}" ]`), but these would be equally or less readable than the `case` option, I think.

Comment: To also strip lines where whitespace (only) precedes `#`, use `grep -v '^\s*#' < /tmp/myfile` instead - this is in line with the `case` solution, given that `read` strips leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Another option (if for some reason someone wanted to avoid `grep`) might be `if [[ $line =~ ^# ]]; then continue; fi`.

Comment: And if someone did not have bash 3 RE, a simple alternative is: `if [[ $line == \#* ]]`

Comment: The grep solution won't work if the while loop needs to modify variables in the current shell, as the loop runs in a subshell (unless bash 4.2 is available and `set -o lastpipe` is used). Other shells may run the while loop in the current shell by default.

Comment: Another option is `[[ $line = \#* ]] && continue`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I stumbled upon this problem recently, so I wanted to share my solution as well.

If you are not against using some python trickery, here it is:

Let this be our file called "my_file.txt":

```
this line will print
this will also print # but this will not
# this wont print either
      # this may or may not be printed, depending on the script used, see below
```

Let this be our bash script called "my_script.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh

line_sanitizer="""import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for l in f.read().splitlines():
        line = l.split('#')[0].strip()
        if line:
            print(line)
"""
echo $(python -c "$line_sanitizer" ./my_file.txt)
```

Calling the script will produce something similar to:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
this line will print
this will also print
```

**Note:** the blank line was not printed

If you want blank lines you can change the script to:

```
#!/bin/sh

line_sanitizer="""import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for l in f.read().splitlines():
        line = l.split('#')[0]
        if line:
            print(line)
"""
echo $(python -c "$line_sanitizer" ./my_file.txt)
```

Calling this script will produce something similar to:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
this line will print
this will also print
```