# pass argument in if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement

in the below code i am trying to search the files.
here, i wanted to exclude the files those are starting with '#'

Please help me on this.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r name
    do
        if [[ $name!= "#" ]]
        then
            find ./2016* -name *files.txt
        fi
done < file.txt
```

getting below error:

```
conditional binary operator expected
syntax error near `"#"'
           if [[ $name!= "#" ]]
```

Comment: `$name != "#"` (spaces are important)

Comment: For such errors, pasting the code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ is always useful.

Comment: Also even with the space you are doing a literal match.

Comment: Why don't you feed the `while` loop with a grepped content? `while read .... done < <(grep -v "^#" file.txt)`. This will grep out the lines starting with `#`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add space between `$name` and `!=`
2. You need to exclude lines that start with `#`. Not just the lines that have only `#`. For this change the pattern to `"#*"`
3. Use the variable `name` in the `find` command.

`#!/bin/bash`

```
while read -r name
    do
        if [[ $name != "#*" ]]
        then
            find ./2016* -name "$name"
        fi
done < file.txt
```

A better way to exclude comment lines is mentioned here - [bash loop skip commented lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488556/bash-loop-skip-commented-lines)

Comment: thank you.
i also need one more argument in the if statement, like below
`if [[ $name != "#*" && $name == "*old*" ]]`
but it didn't worked.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces and double quotations are important. Keep space between `$name` and `!=`
And insert double quotations for `./2016*` and `*files.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r name
 do
    if [[ $name != "#" ]]
    then
       find "./2016*" -name "*files.txt" 
    fi
 done < file.txt
```

Comment: thank you all...
just one question, how search can be treated as the symbol '#' is beginning of the file?

shall i call the value as variable which is defined..
ex:
`variable="#"`
`if [[ $name != "$variable" ]]`